# every retweet, favourite it? Python

Tags: python, api, twitter

i'm a decently new coder and i am currently creating a bot so that every time i retweet something, i favorite it and maybe follow the same person. My code:

```
def retweet(tweet_cid):
    try:
        api.retweet(tweet_cid)
        time.sleep(random.randit(range(50,900)))
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        pass

def follow(screen_name):
try:
    api.create_friendship(screen_name)
    time.sleep(random.randit(range(50,900))) 
except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        pass

def fav(tweet_cid):
    try:
        api.create_favourite(tweet_cid)
        time.sleep(random.randit(range(600,1100)))
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        pass
```

Comment: do you have an error or question? your `follow` function looks like the content needs to be indented

Comment: that was only part of the whole code, i was just looking for the callback function. thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a callback function that calls `follow()` and `fav()` whenever `retweet()` is called instead of using `time.sleep()`.